# Creating a custom TableModel with multiple column headers and row headers

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm attempting to create a JTable that looks like the mockup below:

[image: custom JTable]

The green corner is basically buffer-space for the red column and row headers. The cells don't need to be rendered in the colours pictured; however they need to be distinguishable from the rest of the 'white' cells in the table.

This table also is not editable or selectable; it's merely viewed by a user whilst it is updated.

I know this can be achieved using a DefaultTableModel with custom renders for rows 1,2 && cols 1,2 and adding +2 when setting and getting table values (accounting for the rows and columns that are being used as headers).

### My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a cleaner way of doing this without polluting my table model with these static values used in headers?
2. I've read about extending table models but I'm not sure which class should I extend (DefaultTableModel, AbstractTableModel) and what methods I should override.

Comment: This looks to be more of a display issue and less of a TableModel issue. Have you looked into customizing cell rendering?

Comment: I have. I mentioned it in my question. I'm looking for how to separate out my actual table data from the headers.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002445/trying-to-create-jtable-with-proper-row-header) will help.

Comment: What is the largest number of cells to be rendered?

Comment: Input is limited to 20x20 so including the headers that's 22x22.

Answer (score 6):

> Input is limited to 20x20 so including the headers that's 22x22.

Also consider a `JScrollPane` containing a `JPanel` having `GridLayout` and containing 22x22 instances `JLabel`, or a suitable subclass. This scales easily to several thousand cells.

Addendum: If the need arises, `CellRendererPane` makes a good [flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) renderer, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776211/230513).

If you go with `JTable` for rendering scalability,

1. This is no abuse; it is exactly how `TableModel` is intended to be used. `TableModel` models a rectangular matrix of whatever you decide. `JTable` is just an (efficiently rendered) view of that model.
2. I prefer `AbstractTableModel`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), because `Vector` is rarely the desired data structure. Use whatever container makes your indexing most convenient. `DefaultTableModel` is handy and serves as a guide to extending `AbstractTableModel`. In particular, you'll need a `setValueAt()`.

   ```
   @Override
   public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
       ... // update your data structure
       this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col); // notify the view
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

longer comment, everything depends

1) if is possible for `Columns`

- resize
- reordering

2) if is possible for `Columns`

- filtering
- sorting

a. then you have look at two JTables, first JTable only with TableHeader, simple with removed rows and second full sized JTable with TableHeader and Columns and rows,

b. for interactions betweens two JTableHeader is there
[TableColumnModelListener#columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableColumnModelListener.html#columnMarginChanged%28javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent%29) and `columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e)`

c. everyting put to one `JPanel` inside JScrollPane

d. if you'll change numbers of rows or colums (or filtering / sorting) then you have to notified `JPanel` for rezize `JTable#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` + `Dimension` for ontop `JTable` only with `TableHeader`

very similair way as there (is everything that you needed)

[image][image][image]

(endless kudos for Rob)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableFilterRow extends JFrame implements TableColumnModelListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTable table;
    private JPanel filterRow;

    public TableFilterRow() {
        table = new JTable(3, 5);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(this);
        //  Panel for text fields
        filterRow = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            filterRow.add(new JTextField(" Sum at - " + i));
        }
        columnMarginChanged(new ChangeEvent(table.getColumnModel()));
        getContentPane().add(filterRow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    //  Implement TableColumnModelListener methods
    //  (Note: instead of implementing a listener you should be able to
    //  override the columnMarginChanged and columMoved methods of JTable)
    @Override
    public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        int columns = tcm.getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField) filterRow.getComponent(i);
            Dimension d = textField.getPreferredSize();
            d.width = tcm.getColumn(i).getWidth();
            textField.setPreferredSize(d);
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                filterRow.revalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
        Component moved = filterRow.getComponent(e.getFromIndex());
        filterRow.remove(e.getFromIndex());
        filterRow.add(moved, e.getToIndex());
        filterRow.validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new TableFilterRow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

3) otherwise look [How to Use Raised Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) in the `prepareRederer`

4) this question has nothing to do with type of `TableModel`

Comment: No to both 1 and 2. Regarding 4: the answer I'm trying to get is "Can I avoid having those values you see in red in my String[][] which I use in my `TableModel`

Comment: @Ash then value in the cell(s) could be editable or you want to display only static data ???, I think doesn't important if are values bases on String[][] or whatever