# What's wrong in this code?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable

I'm saving `JTable` content with this code:

```
@override
public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent ce) {

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        int row = getEditingRow();
        int column = getEditingColumn();
        DefaultStyledDocument doc = (DefaultStyledDocument) getCellEditor().getCellEditorValue();

        doc.setDocumentFilter(null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject((DefaultStyledDocument) doc);
        oos.flush();

        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

        oos.close();
        bos.close();

        String query = "update BOX_ROWS "
                    + "set COLUMN1= ? "
                    + "where BOX_ID=" + ID
                    + " and INDEX=" + row;
        pstmt = ReseachAssistantUI.conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setObject(1, data);

        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new MyDocumentFilter());

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MyTable - " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MyTable - " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(pstmt, MyTable.class.getName());
    }

    super.editingStopped(ce);
}
```

and it runs fine on *Windows*. However when I run my app on *Mac OS X* the following message appears:

`MyTable - com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI`

The table pop up editor does have 2 comboboxes on a tool bar, but I can't see what they have to do with this exception. Does anyone know why does it throw this exception? Is there something wrong with the way I serialize the object?

Comment: And where does the exception enter the story?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik When Editting is stopped (When I close the table editor).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the suggestion, but it would be too long.

Comment: *"but it would be too long."*  Did you even read the link?

Comment: The first time you introduce an exception is when you refer to it as "this exception". It would be expected to precede this reference with the introduction to the actual exception that happens. An exception would consist of its class name and its stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik This is all I got. I'm on a PC and can't get it tested again on a mac right away. I set the logger to print to a file the nest time I get a chance to test the app. :)

Comment: @Igor have you checkd your log file?

Comment: You posted your question too soon, then.

Comment: -1 for refusing to provide an SSCCE (for the umpteenth time, isn't it?)

Comment: @kleopatra this is much shorter and clearer than a SSCCE would be for this particular problem.

Comment: _clearer_ as can be easily seen by the wildly guessing comments ;-) Voted to close, as is, it's not answerable.

Comment: @kleopatra The ComboBox itself uses 5 different classes for font editing. How would that be clearer?

Comment: one last time: read the reference given by @AndrewThompson ... **NOW** (if you had you wouldn't mumble _5 different classes for whatever_)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to persist the contents of a changed cell *after* editing concludes but *before* the model is updated; this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513) outlines the normal sequence of events. As you have found, the actual editor component may vary by platform. Instead of overriding `JTable#editingStopped()`, override `TableModel#setValueAt()`, where you *know* the row, column and type of the updated cell. Examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920159/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10263356/230513). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) illustrates using a `JComboBox` as a `CellEditor`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try a set as the answer if it works.

Comment: I finnally got a chance to test it and unfotunately it doesn't work. Here are the  first lines of the stacktrace:

`java.io.NotSerializableException: com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)` ... 

I don't get why the combobox is serialized. I just need the document serialized.

Comment: Serialize? Why not just write the model's data?

Comment: Because I want to save the text styles too. But, how is the combobox serialized here instead of just the textpane document?

Comment: All concrete `javax.swing.text.Document` classes are `Serializable`.

Comment: Why the exception then? Seems to throw it on some versions of _MAC OS X_ only.

Comment: Edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem on your machine, and I'll try it on mine.

Comment: I tried to create a SSCCE, but it has at least 500 lines. That doesn't seem like a Short SCCE at all and I'm not sure it OK to post 500 lines here.