# Does serializing JTextPane's Document, serializes JTextPane's listeners?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, listener, jtextpane

I'm serializing a `JTextPane`'s `Document` in order to persist it's styled text to database. I have a `caretListener` attached to the `JTextPane` and I'm wondering if serializing this `Document` serializies the `caretListener` as well. The reason why I need to know this is because the custom caretListener class containes `JComboBox` and I get the following exception when I attempt the serialization:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxUI
```

I suspect that if the Document contains the caretListener, that's the reason for this exception.

Here's the code that serializes it:

```
DefaultStyledDocument doc = (DefaultStyledDocument) getCellEditor().getCellEditorValue();
doc.setDocumentFilter(null);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject((DefaultStyledDocument) doc);
oos.flush();

byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

oos.close();
bos.close();
```

And then I'm just saving `data` in the database.

**Addendum**

Here's the custom caret listener:

```
MyTextPane textpane = new MyTextPane();
textpane.addCaretListener(new caretListener());
public class caretListener implements CaretListener {

    MyTextpane textArea;
    JToggleButton boldbutton;
    JToggleButton italicbutton;
    JToggleButton underlinebutton;
    JComboBox fontscomboBox;
    JComboBox fontSizecombobox;
    // Methods
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why serializing the document and not just writing your own mechanism. See the warning at the end of each swing class: *Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases*

Comment: @Robin Seemed like the easier thing to do. If it is the cause of the problem, I'll write my own mechanism, tags maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document` is serialized via `Writer` and deserialized via `Reader`. Use the `JTextPane`'s `getEditorKit()` and write/read methods of the kit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really answer the main Question, which is in the title. It would be great if you could add that.

Comment: The problem arose [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13540613/230513), but I have _no_ idea how a `ComboBoxUI` gets dragged in. +1 for `EditorKit`.

Comment: @trashgod Could it be because the caret listener has `JComboBox` fields. Please see the **addendum** in the question.

Comment: @StanislavL I just read that I can't save the alignment with `EditorKit`.

Comment: ...and I'm using `DefaultStyledDocument` instead of `RTFEditorDocument`

Comment: @Igor You can try this one http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html it saves alignment, tables, images etc.

Comment: You should not serialize the listener. Add the listener just once to the JTextPane. Loading the new content won't change the listener of the pane.

Comment: @StanislavL Am I serializing the listener with the above code? I tried using the `AdvancedRTFEditorKit` and I get an exception saying `DefaultStyledDocument cannot be cast into AdvancedRTFEditorDocument`. How can I convert `AdvancedRTFEditorKit` into `DefaultStyledDocument`?

Comment: You don't need serializing listener. Listener is part of controller not model. You got the exception because wrong editor kit is used.

Comment: @StanislavL Actually that was a question :) _'Am I serializing the listener with the code above?'_ And obviously I have to use `AdvancedRTFEditorKit` so how can I avoid getting the exception?

Comment: My answer means you should not serialize it this way but instead write own Reader and Writer. See mentioned above example.

Comment: @StanislavL I'm not sure why, but your way of saving the `Document` works and the errors don't show up. Now I just have to figure out how to use `AdvancedRTFEditorKit` instead of `RTFEditorKit`in order to save the alignment as well. Thanks.