# MouseListener takes ages

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, duration

I've created a Table that is basically a `JPanel` with other panels as rows containing `JTextArea` components to display data. I didn't want to use a `JTable` to have full control by myself.

When a row is clicked on I want it to be highlighted through changing its border. I implemented a `Mouselistener` that does the job for every text area on mouse pressed. It works. It works with 1000 entries, but when I reach more, i.e. 5000 it takes ages for the listener to do his work. Obviously it gets worse the more entries I have. But this doesn't make sense to me, as I only change one rows border, no matter whether there is 1 or 10000 others.

Can anyone point me to the reason for this? Even if I put a `System.out` right after "mouse pressed" it takes ages for the output. So I guess its not the executed methods (that are not time consuming at all) themselves.

Comment: The cost is due to the lines 243 and 654, says my crystal ball.

Comment: You should *really* consider using a table with an appropriate cell renderer for this, as it does all this sort of stuff well (without 'taking ages').  If you want us to help debug the current approach, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *.. I only change one rows border"*  Likely triggering a call to get the preferred size of the ***parent*** container..

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct; as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10263356/230513), `JTable` is an easy way to get [flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) rendering.

Comment: After trying a JTable (still uncustomized) I see there is no other way. It's a pain as I've been working for 2 weeks on a selfmade table with my whole program being finished, if there were no performance issues. For future reference: My custom table consisting of swing elements took roughly 6 minutes to load and display 30000 rows, while JTable needs 2 seconds for the job. So thanks for pushing me into the right direction, even if I've got loads of work in front of me :)