# JTable headers on left side and cells on right [explained with image]

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

As second picture says, I want to anchor 'HeaderModel' left and 'CellModel' right. If its possible...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `JTable` will display whatever data is returned by the `getValueAt()` method. You can change a cell's *appearance* using a suitable [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). You can obtain a copy of the default header renderer, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6644956/230513). This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005006/230513) shows how to apply the renderer to the table's first column.

[image]