# Java Swing Custom TableCellRenderer loses its Grid lines

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am playing around with some styles and ran into something I cant seem to find an answer for. I created a custom `TableCellRenderer` and overrode `getTableCellRenderComponent`, basically just changing the background color:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean    isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
    Component l = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
    l.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    return l;
}
```

My problem is that when i call this to change say my table header background color, it removes the tables grid lines

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(k).setHeaderRenderer(newCustomTableCellRenderer());
```

Not sure why this is happening. How to fix it?

Comment: The border is supplied by the look and feel specific header

Answer (score 3):

As @MadProgrammer notes, "The border is supplied by the look and feel specific header." You can obtain a copy of the UI delegate's renderer, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6644956/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005006/230513), and decorate it as desired. A related example using common defaults is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513).