# JTable with customized row and columns headers

Tags: java, swing, csv, header, jtable

I want to have a `JTable` for representing a CSV file with both row as well as column headers, just like MS Excel provides, which are initially set as `att1`, `att2`, `att3` (for column headers) and `row1`, `row2`, `row3` (for row headers). I need to have such an interface where header values could be set if they are already present in a file.

If the first column contains header values,then instead of `row1`, `row2`, `row3`, given values could be set as row headers, and, if the first row contains header values,then instead of `att1`, `att2`, `att3` given values could be set for column.

I don't know how to do the same with row. 
for columns,

```
String[] hname = new String[dm.getColumnCount()];
    for(int j=0;j<dm.getColumnCount();j++)
   {       
   hname[j]=dm.getValueAt(0, j).toString();}
    dm.removeRow(0);
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(hname));
    dm.setDataVector(dm.getDataVector(), v);
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try googling JTable Row Header:

[JTable Row Header Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434933/jtable-row-header-implementation)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TableRowHeaderExample.htm